# @angular/pwa installation failed

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to install @angular/pwa.

while doing this, I'm getting following error.

```
The package @angular/pwa@16.1.2 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Packages successfully installed.
Path "/src/@app/app.module.ts" does not exist.
```

How to resolve this error.

even though the terminal says Packages successfully installed, because of the Path error, I'm not able to see any changes in index.html, package.json files.

[image]

Comment: Try this

```
1) ng new <project name> (wait or skip install packages)
2) ng add @angular/pwa
```
it is worked

Comment: It is a monorepo?